# Can I make Behat/ZombieJS/Mink simulate a click on a "non-link" element, to fire JS listeners?

Tags: behat, zombie.js, mink

I am using [Behat](http://mink.behat.org/index.html) for testing, with the [ZombieJS](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) driver, and everything is working very well so far, but there is one thing that bothers me, I can't seem to figure out how to get Behat to simulate a click on a non-link element. I guess this comes from Mink being a "cross-browser" driver, and it doesn't really make sense to click on non-link elements. For my use case though, I need it, because there are several elements on the page that have javascript event listeners attached to them, and I want to test these functionalities.

I tried using

```
Then I follow "div.sa"
```

But it fails with the expected error:

```
01. Link with id|title|alt|text "div.sa" not found.
```

Since it's not a link element. There is a similar step in Behat:

I press "button.class"

But this one is only for buttons.

Is there a way I could get Behat click on elements that are not  tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I believe so, but you'll need to write a custom step, something along these lines (if you're using a subclass of `MinkContext`.

```
/**
 * @When /^I click the something$/
 */
public function iClickTheSomething() 
{
    $something = $this->getSession()
                      ->getPage()
                      ->find("css", "div.sa")
                      ->click();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

With some error handling:

```
/** Click on the element with the provided xpath query
 *
 * @When /^(?:|I )click on the element "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iClickOnTheElement($locator)
{
    $session = $this->getSession(); // get the mink session
    $element = $session->getPage()->find('css', $locator); // runs the actual query and returns the element

    // errors must not pass silently
    if (null === $element) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not evaluate CSS selector: "%s"', $locator));
    }

    // ok, let's click on it
    $element->click();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my adaptation of the answer by Comstar. The same functionality is achieved, however, it seems simpler to me to do it this way.

```
/**
 * @Then /^I click on "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iClickOn($arg1)
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

    $findName = $page->find("css", $arg1);
     if (!$findName){
        throw new Exception($arg1." could not be found");
    }
    else {
        $findName->click();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I execute a click event, so that the current URL be equal to javascript:

```
$this->iClickOnTheElementWithXPath(‘//div[@class="'.$arg2.'"]/div/div[@class="edit"]/a[text()="'.$arg1.'"]‘);
```

In the page html:

```
<a onclick="editForm('Avatar')" href="javascript:;">Modifier</a>
```